# Call to undefined function odbc_connect() php 7

Tags: php

I'm testing out php 7 and have come across this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

From the doc page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php php 7 is not listed as supported.

Does anyone have a way around this or know when it will be supported?

Thanks@

Comment: what do you have against PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: nothing but it would require a lot of code changes

Comment: well php7 doesn't support your driver, so anything you do wil require code changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is looking for nonexistent magical solution.

Comment: Wow it's out for 2 weeks and it's a non existent magical solution?  Do you have information where they plan on not supporting it?  I can wait a little while.

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows environment. odbc_connect() function doesn't need any dll or extension. I should never report "undefined function".

Comment: Good question! Look out for the second answer - it worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DOC page does list PHP 7, so just install php-odbc and you should be good to go. Currently using it myself on RedHat EL7 with Remi php7.

Answer (score 21):

There is written in doc: ODBC support doesn't need any extension dll. It is true in PHP 5.x, I had to remove "extension=php_odbc.dll" from ini file.

But in PHP 7 I had to put it back.

I found the file "ext/php_odbc.dll" in the new PHP 7 directory again. It works for me :).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem.  However according to the link you provided PHP7 is in fact supported. So I'm not sure why you have so many comments telling you to go re-write your code.

This is what ultimately fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php-odbc
```

Followed by restarting Apache.

Comment: I had to do sudo apt install php7.0-odbc for it to work (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 5):

PHP 7.2.7, add **extension=php_odbc.dll** in **php.ini** file while either using database as MS Access or Sql Server
C:\xxxxxx\php\php.ini

*no semicolon before to **extension=php_odbc.dll**

Comment: That was already given multiple times. Is there anything new you'd like to add?

Answer (score 2):

Just enble "php_odbc.dll" extension by removing the semicolon and restart Apache.

If there is no such line in php.ini, simply create it on yourself (you will find many similar lines in php.ini) by adding: `extension=php_odbc.dll` and then restart Apache.

If Apache does not start or cannot load php_odbc.dll, look into to the ext-Folder of PHP, if there is such a DLL called php_odbc.dll. If there is no such DLL, Xampp/PHP7 does not support ODBC natively. In that case you should install an older Xampp Version with PHP 5.x

Answer (score 1):

From php.ini file:

```
> ; Notes for Windows environments :
> ;
> ; - ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
> ; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
```

But, in PHP 7, ODBC is not by default. Explicit

```
extension=odbc
```

worked for me (new syntax recommended)

Edit: 
If your architecture is x64
you must use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
instead of C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error message:

> Redhat PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> odbc_connect()

On Redhat Linux 7 you run:

```
yum install php-odbc
```

You will get these packages marked in red:

[image]

Code sample to test your connection via php command line run: php [filename].php

```
<?php
// filename: test-connection.php by running command -> php test-connection.php
$connect = odbc_connect("Driver=FreeTDS; Server=sbase.company.ca; Port=1433; TDS_Version=8; ClientCharset=UTF-8; Database=mydbase",'company\\user', 'password');
$query = "SELECT * from mytable";
// perform the query
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
// fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
        $suid = odbc_result($result, 1);
        $uid = odbc_result($result, 2);
        $gid = odbc_result($result, 3);
        $name = odbc_result($result, 4);
        print("$name|$suid|$uid|$gid\n");
}
// close the connection
odbc_close($connect);
?>
```

Enjoy!