# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Tags: php, odbc

I have issue with ODBC connection.
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()*

My PHP version on server is  7.3.12 (ubuntu)

On localhost i do have version 7.3.11 and everything is fine after adding "extension=php_odbc.dll" to *php.ini*

But when i add this line to *php.ini* on server,  i am still receiving error.

Have someone ever met this issue?

Thank you very much

Comment: _“But when i add this line to php.ini on server, i am still receiving error.”_ - of course you do - an Ubuntu system doesn’t care about any `.dll` files, that’s a Windows thing.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how can i enable this function on ubuntu server?

Comment: Specifically you need this answer from the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287834

Comment: I already did sudo apt-get install php-odbc and also added line to php.ini