# PHP odbc_connect() Undefined function

Tags: php, odbc

I wanted to connect a SQL database to my PHP file, but when I run the `odbc_connect` function, it gives an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

This is my code:

```
$connection = odbc_connect('MyDatabaseName', 'MyUsername', 'MyPassword');
```

Comment: [click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+Uncaught+Error%3A+Call+to+undefined+function+odbc_connect) for existing information on solving this error.

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this is not related to the SQL _language_. You can add a tag for the dbms used instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function odbc\_connect() php 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321203/call-to-undefined-function-odbc-connect-php-7)

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

Linux systems based on debian/ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install php-odbc
```

Linux systems based on redhat/centos

```
yum update
dnf install php-odbc
```

Right after if you are using nginx:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Or if not, if you are using apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Or use:

```
systemctl restart your-program
```